# Making a phone call from SIM900A with raspberry to mobile

Tags: raspbian

I connect the SIM900A with raspberry and the two LEDS blink red.
This is the code for making a call and it runs without errors.

```python
import serial
import os, time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
port.write(b'AT\r')

rcv = port.read(10)
print(rcv)
time.sleep(1)

port.write(b'ATDxxxxxxxx;\r')
print("Calling…")

time.sleep(30)

port.write(b'ATH\r')
print("Hang Call…")'
```

The output is:

```
b'\r\r\nOK\r\n'
Calling…  '
```

But there is no call on my phone??

Note: When run AT command it give me ERROR

Answer (score 0):

1. Try it with interactive terminal, e.g. `screen /dev/ttyS0 9600`, and type the AT commands there. See if you can make a call from there.
2. You don't check the response of `ATD` - what if it returns an error and you don't know?

Comment: I am new to SIM modules , what you mean by interactive terminal ,

Comment: sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 115200
here i run ATD

Comment: Minicom is as good as screen. Does the `ATD` command typed there work? If not make it work with minicom first and leave the python part for later.

Comment: yes , sometimes it doesn't .
the last time it gives ERROR

Comment: You'll have to figure out a pattern when it works (e.g. after power up) and when it doesn't (e.g. repeated calls) and then find a way to bring the modem back to the state where it works before each call. `AT&F` may be a good start. Anyway, this question doesn't really belong here.

Comment: can you provide me with something useful like link to tutorials or something related?

Comment: I’m sure you can use Google yourself ;)